# Any way to get "users online" from google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there any way to get "users online" from google analytics? 
I have tried a lot of api but there is no way to get "users online".
Real Time Reporting API Private Beta - is closed betta.(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get#examples)
GAPI (https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface) does not have any suitable way to get this data.

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend using the Real-time API to detect how many users are online.   Unless you plan on caching it every five minutes or something.  You are going to run out of Quota quite quickly if you try and do it live.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page you linked to has a form you can fill out to get access to the Real Time Reporting API. If you fill out that form, you'll be granted access.

Comment: Yes, but I want to put in a php script, and that link has key which will expire in couple of days, but I need a permanent one.

Comment: Once you are whitelisted, the auth process works exactly the same as all other GA APIs.

Comment: I dont get it. I get a result link https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/realtime?ids=ga%3A****&metrics=rt%3AactiveUsers&key={YOUR_API_KEY} Where I need YOUR_API_KEY - I tried different Keys but no one fits.

Comment: You need to get an access token to make API requests. You can read about how that's done here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2